# Simulation Lorentzian function with FFT

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, simulation

I need to utilize Fourier transform on Lorentzian function with `ln` scale.
I know Lorentzian function after FFT is `exp(-pi|k|)`, it seems right.

[image]

I do that on `ln` scale.  It supposed to be linear and no oscillation at all.
However there is oscillation. I lost it totally.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
a =1 
N = 500
x =np.linspace(-5,5,N)
lorentz = (a/np.pi) * (1/(a**2 + x**2))
fourier = (fft.fft(lorentz))
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax1.loglog(abs(fourier[0:int(N/2)]),basey=np.e)
ax1.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

How could I solve the problem?

Follow comment said:
Here is

```
x =np.linspace(-20,20,N)
```

[image]
It seems like postpone the oscillation but still there.

after adding hamming window :

[image]
Hamming window postpones it also.

I try to extend to

```
x =np.linspace(-60,60,N)
```

[image]

It seems correct(related to a and wider range and point interval). But I'm curious about what happened.

Comment: Hi Huang alex, keep in mind the FFT only works properly when at least **2 periods** of a function are included in the data points (Nyquist)

Comment: The [Lorentzian function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html) is aperiodic, so you can't get 2 periods. But Goodies is probably right that this is an effect from truncating the signal to the domain [-5, 5]. Multiply with a windowing function before FFT as a mitigation, `fft(lorentz * np.hanning(N))`. Also, try increasing the domain to a wider range, say `x = np.linspace(-20, 20, N)` and see whether that helps.

Comment: @PascalGetreuer It's seems correct when I extend my signal to wider range.(However it's lower sampling rate) 
When I try to maintain the same sampling rate, these oscillation happened again.
BTW I change the `a` index, It does not help.
I'm confused about that. 
I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: @Goodies Thx. I'm grateful that you mention the important advice.

Answer (score 0):

Pascal's remark helps to explain. At first glance, I felt the oscillating distortion you show was related to analysis window boundaries. When your signal is not zero on either side of the window, the FFT analysis will find a step, which results into "butterfly" problems that have nothing to do with your input signal. Hamming window - raised cosine - can solve that, but if the hamming has to do too much smoothing on the edges, you analyse a signal you don't have !

Nice to see the tip to enlarge the analysis window worked in this case.. so you took a larger range around zero, you get the expected result for a Lorentzian function. My science expertise is too limited to actually understand why this particular spectrum is the correct result.

Attempt to explain why 2xNyquist requirement is relevant: you are using signal analysis tools in the real domain (not complex input). For FFT analysis of real samples, the analysis window should accommodate 2 periods of the lowest frequency you are interested in. You are investigating an impulse response, so its "period" shape will be the *only* one you are interested in. By taking a larger interval around 0 into account, you have put your impulse response in the middle. Hamming window will be around 1 there. When your analysis window is wide enough, and a Hamming window is applied, the FFT will see proper input (zero on either side !) and yield proper, smooth output, as if you are analysing a very low frequency periodic signal.

My experience with FFT tools is in the field of speech research. In a speech sample, there is a pitch. The lowest frequency or "f0" of the speaker. For males, you have e.g. typically 100 Hz pitch. With a sampling frequency of 20kHz, a single pitch period  will require 200 samples. Two pitch periods require 400 samples. I prefer setting FFT order instead of analysis window. Order 9 FFT is 512 samples in your window, it  will yield 256 frequencies. Order 10 is 512 result frequencies, requiring 1024 samples, etc. The hamming window I use in my spectrum tool is always the full window, not a truncated window.